# Load Assetbundle with new Vuforia Marker / Dataset in Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have an app that loads a new scene via assetbundle, the problem is, I need to update the app sometimes, but I can't update the core which is available in the ios and android store. So I need to load new content and new vuforia datasets through an assetbundle. The Vuforia Cloud is not an option.

I know it is not possible to load scripts through an assetbundle. But maybe there is another way of loading a new vuforia dataset via internet / assetbundle?

I am using Unity 5 and Vuforia 5 and the app is developed for ios and android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use AssetBundles to do this. You should download the dataset using WWW to a local file, load it using DataSet.Load, then activate it using ObjectTracker.ActivateDataSet (DataSet dataSet). Something along these lines (untested):

```
    ObjectTracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();

    DataSet dataSet = objectTracker.CreateDataSet ();
    if (dataSet.Load ("<pathtodataset>", QCARUnity.StorageType.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE))
    {
        // Assumes objectTracker not running. if it is running at this point, stop it before this line
        objectTracker.ActivateDataSet (dataSet);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a solution. What I do is, just loading the .xml and .dat of an dataset from server, store it on the SD Card of the device.. And when I load the asset bundle, which includes a whole scene where the dataset is active, it works. So the core knows that the dataset exists

Comment: @Jenny can you also include scripts in the asset bundles?

Comment: No you can't.. Scripts are always stored in the core app unfortunately:(